# Galaxy Tab 10.1 usable screen resolution (- the menu bar)

Tags: android, resolution, screen-resolution, galaxy-tab

I know that the screen resolution is 1280×800px but Honeycomb's bottum menu bar makes this a tad smaller, but how much smaller?

Has google published the height of the menubar? (the one that can't be taken away as it has the home/back etc buttons)

I want to know this because when I draw a fullscreen background for the Tab I want to know the exact size as to get a pixel perfect result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The height of the menu bar on Honeycomb is 48 pixels, for devices with 1280x800 pixels at least.

Comment: Cheers. Where did you find this?

Comment: This can be easily measured by checking the size of the main view of an app running on Honeycomb. You can also Google similar results.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its 48 on Samsung Galaxy P7500 10.1

Answer (score 0):

Use http://supportdetails.com/ to find out the size. Remember. You can rotate a tablet!

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.